# Hibernate all columns in composite key - returns no POJO object

Tags: hibernate

This is my hbm.xml file structure.

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="customer" table="Customer" schema="Schem">
    <composite-id name="id" class="Customerid">
        <key-property name="code" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="CODE" length="10" />
        </key-property>
        <key-property name="name" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="NAME" length="10" />
        </key-property>
        <key-property name="address" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="ADDRESS" length="100" />
        </key-property>
        <key-property name="contactnumber" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="CONTACTNUMBER" length="15" />
        </key-property>
    </composite-id>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

but in the database, if any one column of a row is empty. then hibernate does not return any Customer Object and return null. What I am guessing is because all columns are in composite id that's why it's returning null object if any one column is empty in that row.
How to get the hibernate POJO object Customer when I only have code value available?

Comment: what I mean is Composite-key has columns which are not part of the primary key. but I don't know how to get Customer Object by using only 'code' column.

Answer (score 0):

an id/primary key must **not be null** and be **unique**. include only the columns which form the primary key in the compositeId mapping. To get one instance by id use

```
Customer customer = session.get(Customer.class, new Customer(<id properties));
```